# I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 on an external hard drive but it won't boot Windows 8.1 when I remove it

Tags: boot, system-installation

I found a list of instructions for installing Ubuntu on an external hard drive that had lots of positive feedback.

As far as Ubuntu booting when the external hard drive is plugged in is concerned, that seems to be working perfectly.  However, when I unplug it and turn on my computer, I'm greeted with GNU GRUB version 2.02.

I then plugged the external drive in to see if I could navigate my internal drive and it's contents, and I found it, but it appears to be removable media.  Both the external drive and the internal drive are within the media folder in Ubuntu.  Is there any way I can fix this so Windows 8.1 boots when the external drive isn't plugged in?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. It is because your ubuntu boot manager in BIOS which is probably the first entry searches for GRUB which resides on your external HDD. So your external HDD needs to be plugged in during booting.
If you want to boot without external HDD to Windows then the only option is to select the respective entry from BIOS each time you boot.

Comment: When the external HDD is unplugged, it gives me a black and white command line for GRUB.  When it's plugged in, there doesn't seem to be a way to boot Windows from there.  As Will mentioned, I might've accidentally installed GRUB on my internal HDD on accident, but I'm not quite sure.  My boot order seems to be in the correct order to boot Windows from the start, it just doesn't.  In Ubuntu, my internal HDD is inside the media folder.

Comment: The GRUB should show boot entries for all the available OS on your PC

Comment: Its quite strange that Windows option is not mentioned. Try booting Windows from the boot menu option during startup.

Comment: I'm not sure (which is obvious) if I can boot from the GRUB command line itself.  I tried some methods I found in my search for a solutions but yielded only not being able to boot because of security.  Would I be able to uninstall Ubuntu and try again?

Comment: According to me, when you plug your external HDD and boot then you should get a grub menu with Windows booting as one of the options

Comment: If this is not the case then get into boot setup of your PC by pressing the prescribed key and select Windows boot manager to boot into Windows. According to your description​ I am afraid that you may need to do this each time you boot

Comment: I'll see if it lets me do that and I'll let you know the result.

Answer (score 0):

My uncle referred me to a link for boot-repair.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Everything went excellent after installing it and having it repair my boot.  Well, Linux won't boot from USB or my external HDD when I change the boot order but my main goal was to get my access to Windows back.  Thank you for all of your suggestions!